# Why doesn't the .remove() method also affect the variable it's being set on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Javascript and jQuery so maybe this is a basic concept, but in the following code:

```
var toRemove = $("p").remove();   
$("div").append(toRemove);
```

I remove the p element which I saw work in the UI and then I append it. Because it's removed, I would expect it to not append anything. But in the UI I see that it did. Why does it do that?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4mthn93z/

Comment: The removed DOM object is stored in the toRemove variable. You are then appending that DOM object stored in the variable to your div element. That's why one could expect it to append "something" which is just the element that you've removed from the DOM set.

Comment: The DOM is a data structure of elements (nodes) linked together. Calling `.remove()` takes an element out of that data structure but does not obliterate it.

Comment: It's like defining an object, say `var a = {...};` and adding it to an array. If you remove the object from the array `a` still exists, it's just no longer apart of the array.

Comment: If you apply the above to your example, `$("p")` would be the object and the array would be the DOM or the webpage

Answer (score 2):

Generally jQuery methods, when called on a collections of nodes, returns the same collection. This is what enables you to chain methods. E.g `$("#id").html("Some contnet").hide();`

Just because something has been removed from the DOM doesn't mean the javascript/jquery object has ceased to exist, it's just no longer part of the DOM. By assigning the result of the method to a variable, you have saved those objects for later use. This is actually a very handy feature.

Answer (score 1):

Because toRemove is a function. 
You can try..

```
var toRemove = $("p").remove();   
$("div").append(toRemove());
```

Comment: The jQuery method `$(...).remove()` does not return a function. Your answer might make sense if it was `var toRemove = $("p").remove;`